# Time complexity of a machine which combines Insertion Sort and Quicksort

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, sorting, quicksort

Given a machine that sorts an array of length $n$ with the following algorithm:

1. Sort first $2\sqrt{n} + 1$ elements of array with **Insertion Sort**.(Check [Insertion Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-insertion-sort/))
2. Select the median of the whole array (after its first $2\sqrt{n} + 1$ length part is sorted from step 1) as the pivot then partition the array.(Check [Quicksort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/))
3. Do both above steps for both partitions resulted from step 2 in a recursive way.

**Suggest a recursive function that computes the time complexity of the above machine in its worst case.**

$\rule{17.5cm}{0.4pt}$

As I see it's somehow a mixture of **Quicksort** and **Insertion sort** and every time the machine wants to quick sort a partition of length n we are sure that first $2\sqrt{n} + 1$ elements are sorted.
we know:

- Quicksorting a sorted array of length n is from $O(n\log n$) and Insertion sorting it is from $O(n)$.
- worst case of both Quicksort and Insertion sort is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Please credit the original source where you encountered this question.

Comment: It's a college task. I assume it must be creditable.

Comment: Insertion sort for n items is O(n^2). But what time is insertion sort for an array of size 2 sqrt(n) + 1?

Comment: ("to credit" in "higher education" means *give due credit to originator and source*, not *argue the contents is plausible*.) `Select the median of the whole array (after its first [part is sorted])` is that what the original problem statement says? The median doesn't change with permutation. (If it was *median (middle) of the sorted part*, please give the frequent case *input is almost ordered* explicit consideration.)

Answer (score 0):

The worst case for Quicksort happens when each partitioning divides an array of size n into sub arrays of size 1 and n-1. In your case, is that possible? Why isn’t it possible? What is the worst outcome of partitioning if the pivot is the median of 2k numbers? So what is the worst case in your algorithm?